# Changing Copyright "Organization" in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, organization, copyright-display

I have already tried multiple ways.

- defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions 
  '{ORGANIZATIONNAME="YourNameHere";}'
- Also i've tried changing the "Organization", section under Project Document.

Why will it still not change? Meaning whenever I make new project it still defaults to the old one.

> //  Copyright (c) 2012 IWantToChangeThis. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third way, which is to change the company name in your Address Book card, but I'm guessing that's not your problem. What any of these methods does is change the organization name for any new files you create in the project, and will not change the files that have already been created. If you want to change the existing files, you can do a find and replace for "__MyCompanyName__" across the whole project. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I actually want it to change it for every new project I create, but whenever I still create new projects it still defaults to the old organization name.

Comment: So the address book part is actually right, I when to the Address book and changed the organization under Me, and it worked. It seems like it was overriding all of the other solutions.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an application that is already in the App Store... this can easily be accomplished by adjusting the metadata online in Apple's iTunes connect. No need to re-release your binary.

Comment: Oh I am actually talking about the comments for the copy right ect